# How to get the StageName in Opportunity in apex

Tags: apex, opportunity, selectoption

This might work. But I need the one from the Opportunity object.

```
public List<SelectOption> getopenPresentationOptions(){

        List<SelectOption> optns = new List<Selectoption>();

       optns.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Prospecting','Prospecting'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Qualification','Qualification'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Needs Analysis','Needs Analysis'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Value Proposition','Value Proposition'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Id. Decision Makers','Id. Decision Makers'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Perception Analysis','Perception Analysis'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Proposal/Price Qoute','Proposal/Price Qoute'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Negotiation/Review','Negotiation/Review'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Closed Won','Closed Won'));
       optns.add(new SelectOption('Closed Lost','Closed Lost'));

       return optns;
    }
```

Comment: Please describe your question in detail for identifying your requirement clearly...  Do you want opportunity stageName picklist values in custom picklist... ?

Comment: Yes I need the opportunity Stagename for picklist/selectoption..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch picklist values using this code:....

```
    List<SelectOption> options =  new List<SelectOption>();    
    options.add(new selectOption('None','--- None ---'));    
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Opportunity.stagename.getDescribe();    
    List<Schema.picklistEntry> vls = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();    
    for(Schema.picklistEntry v:vls)    
    {    
        options.add(new selectOption(v.getLabel(),v.getValue()));                    
    }
```